# Instagram Api: getting all media in a range of coordinates

Tags: python, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to get all the media for a square of coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve media from Intagram's API in a given radius of a coordinate pair by performing a `GET` request on the `/media/search` [endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search).

Break up your given area into 4 quadrants, and feed the lat/long of the center of those quadrants into this API.

Then the area covered in your four `GET` requests would cover your given topology as follows:

[image]

The reasoning behind having more compact circles being placed within your quadrilateral area is because, when your points don't perfectly form a shape which have perpendicular lines, but rather a convex area, such as a trapezoid. A single simple shape in the center of your area won't cover as much area as you would like. This is evident from the image below:

[image]

However, if you were to have an arrangement of non-overlapping circles within your containing space, you could cover as large a proportion of the space as possible:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: What if i want the entire media from USA? how it done the way you suggested above?

Comment: Hi Tal, thats a good question. You have to understand that Instagram (and most REST services) rate limit the endpoints they expose. Grabbing media from the entire US is not possible because Instagram does not have a firehose API like Twitter does.  Your best approach is to parrallelize the task, and break the country up into regions and perform the API request on those points. That way you get as much content sent back to you from every request you make. Also be forewarned, these companies will block your IP address if you exceed their predetermined limit (to prevent web scrapping).